# DMN Feel Expression to filter List of List Complex Objects based on a condition

Tags: dmn

I have list of "components" complex object need to FILTER the component list
WHEN
components[].code.coding[1].code="48005-3" return components[x]
x = matched index in the components list

I'm looking for the following final out put

IF components[].code.coding[1].code="48005-3" THEN return
components[].valueCodeableConcept.coding[1].code

```
{ "components": [
  {
                        "code": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://loinc.org",
                                    "code": "48005-3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "valueCodeableConcept": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://varnomen.hgvs.org",
                                    "code": "p.Val455Met"
                                }
                            ],
                            "text": "V455M"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "code": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://loinc.org",
                                    "code": "53037-8"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "valueCodeableConcept": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://loinc.org",
                                    "code": "LA26333-7"
                                }
                            ],
                            "text": "Variant of Uncertain Significance"
                        }
                    }
]
}
```

I wrote the following logic in the DMN Business Knowledge Model in the DMN Editor (sandbox.kie.org)
(context)
for aComponent in components return
for aCoding in aComponent.code.coding return
for aCode in aCoding return if aCode.code="48005-3"" = true then aComponent else null

its returning entire components content